# How to interpret "and" and "over"

Tags: meaning

> Include title cards and additional graphics over cards and picture

It's about video production.

Does it mean:

**Include (title cards) and (additional graphics over cards and picture).**

Or

**Include (title cards and additional graphics) over (cards and picture).**

?

Is it context-dependent or is there any other way to clearly identify the structure of this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely context-dependent.  My instinct is to interpret it as your second example, but without context we cannot know which makes more sense.

It could even be interpreted in a third way, if we allow for polysyndeton (the practice of using a conjunction between *every* element of a list):

**Include (title cards) and (additional graphics over cards) and (picture)**.

That seems pretty unlikely to me, not least because polysyndeton is more often an error than a stylistic choice, but the grammar does permit it.